# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnectedError: Server disconnected

Tags: asynchronous

I get an error in the parser. The error refers, as I understand it, to this code, I tried to set a limit, it did not work. I also tried disabling HTTP keep-alive as a workaround. To do this, you can create a custom TCPConnector with the force_close parameter set to True and pass it to ClientSession.

```
C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/Пользователь/Desktop/профи/pythonProject5/full_parser.py
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\профи\pythonProject5\full_parser.py", line 120, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\профи\pythonProject5\full_parser.py", line 112, in main
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(gather_items(categories))
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\профи\pythonProject5\full_parser.py", line 105, in gather_items
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\профи\pythonProject5\full_parser.py", line 69, in get_items
    async with session.get(url=url,
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 559, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 898, in start
    message, payload = await protocol.read()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 616, in read
    await self._waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnectedError: Server disconnected

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
async def gather_items(categories):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []


        for category in categories:
            task = asyncio.create_task(get_items(session, category))
            tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```